# How to get a google photo's album thumbnail preview image in my website

Tags: php, jquery

How to get a google photo's album thumbnail preview image in my website

For example , if we share album link on facebook it gives us a photo preview

Comment: I am trying to use a url of google photo album ,  from url i need a thumbnail image preview of google photo album in my website, plz help me

Comment: I know what your question says, but you need to try something first. How do you know it's PHP and jQuery? This isn't a site for you to ask people to do things for you